# Passing this variable as reference in php

Tags: php

In PHP5, I am getting an ugly warning message when passing this variable as reference when running below code..,

```
<?php 
random_string_function($string1, $string2, $p); 
echo "Percent: $p%"; 
?>
```

any help ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's configurable in **php.ini** just do `allow_call_time_pass_reference = Off` !